# Using YouTube v3 API to retrieve a list of videos for a channel without live events

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am using the YouTube v3 API to retrieve a list of videos using this URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=[APIKEY]&channelId=[ChannelID]&part=snippet,id&order=date&type=video&maxResults=25
```

However, YouTube includes upcoming live broadcast results for this query. The live results can be place-holder the author puts days in advance and don't contain any real content so I rather not show them to the users.

I could filter the live results in my code, but I would rather the user sees a fixed number of videos per query (e.g. "25"), and filtering after the query would result in a lower number.

I tried calling:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=[APIKEY]&channelId=[ChannelID]&part=snippet,id&order=date&type=video**&eventType=completed**&maxResults=25
```

But it only returns completed live events and doesn't show videos that were not broadcast live.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the publishedBefore property
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Comment: I'm not sure how that would help, I'm trying to list all videos for a channel, the live events have placeholders that are created days in advance and are listed in the search results.  If I use the publishedBefore option, it will also filter out non-live videos I want to list.