# Listing my YouTube Channels Videos *without* ended live stream and without OAuth

Tags: youtube-data-api

I have a [tiny insignificant YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-uPZ7GJiC76pWl-9yyzUng) channel I've started live-streaming to. Once the stream ends I end up with a lovely video (of which I have 3) that I'd like to link to from a website. I cannot figure out how to get a list of all the finished videos (**without** ended live stream(s)) using YouTube's v3 API and simple key-based access.

A [similar question has been posed here before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41659993/using-youtube-v3-api-to-retrieve-a-list-of-videos-for-a-channel-without-live-eve), but I have quite a bit to elaborate on my attempts which will hopefully trigger an idea for someone else. Thus, I thought I might as well make a new question. Here's what I've tried:

## Attempt 1

First I tried just to search for all the content related to my channel like so:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UC-uPZ7GJiC76pWl-9yyzUng&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

This only returns 2 of the 3 videos currently on the channel, although the `totalResults` field curiously says 5?! Setting the `type` field to `video` reduces this number to 4, but doesn't increase the returned items.

## Attempt 2

Next, I found out that actually listing a channels upload items is apparently the way to go via this request:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=UU-uPZ7GJiC76pWl-9yyzUng&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

This curiously enough returned 4 results. Upon further inspection it seems one of the results is a link to the page of the ended live stream, but *nothing* in the returned data (as far as I can tell) allows me to tell it apart from the resulting video. I've provided the [returned Json on a pastebin](http://pastebin.com/JznxvwbL). The only bad idea I've had so far is the `publishedAt` field which seems to end right as the stream ended, and the resulting video is of course published somewhat later. But this is such a flimsy approach to rely on and forces me to cross-check videos to determine which video may be confused with the live stream.

I've also not been able to find any API request the exclusively returns the link to the ended live stream allowing me to filter it out.

### Sidenote

If I **could** use OAuth, using the following query seems to give me exactly what I need:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&forMine=true&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

3 videos only. However the `forMine` tag is unusable when just accessing the YouTube API via the simple API Key.

I'm open to any and all ideas - thanks in advance!

Comment: It would appear that YouTube eventually removes the lingering live-stream from the returned data. So unfortunately, making API calls will currently not exhibit the problem I face once I conclude a live stream. :(

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any problems.
I think that your issue is that you were not able to see your new upload.
And if that is so, then probably was still in the system being formatted for the web.
As it is a large file, it will take a while.

At time of this reply, you have 4 videos. 3 are long and 1 is an intro/demo called "PlanMixPlay - Teaser 1".

To remove this video from results in code if that is your requirement, just need to ad in this during your for loop.

```
if($video_ID == 'IyN5LuvvQlw'){
    break;
 }
```

Comment: It would appear that YouTube eventually removes the lingering 'livestream' listing from the API returned data. So as of right now - the API only returns the correct 4 vids. Unfortunately, I expect it'll return when I conclude my next livestream this coming Sunday. So while I appreciate the effort, your answer doesn't solve my problem.

The teaser has a fixed and permanent video ID - and your suggestion would remove it - but my problem isn't with the teaser, it's with the linger live-stream ID which is new and unknown each and every time eliminating the option to filter it via its ID.

Comment: Under the "snipet" attribute there is a "liveBroadcastContent" attribute that might help. But I never used it and have not looked at live stream's.

Comment: I *think* I looked at that without any success, but I'll give it another go in the near future. My understanding is that the bounty on the question simply disappears if no answer is voted up. Despite the fact that my problem remains unsolved, there's only 4 hours to go and you did extend an effort to find a solution - so I'll award it to you.

Comment: @Gazoo . thanks, though I am sorry that I was not more help. Perhaps you need to look at the info in stages to see if it might help. Might be a "flag" of sorts in the response that is only there for a short time.